# What unit is returned by the ncf::correlog function?

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, moran-index

I'm using the `correlog` function from the `ncf` package to figure out the distance between points at which spatial autocorrelation isn't detected. I was wondering what unit was being returned in the correlogram or even in the object's `mean.of.class` element.

```
RNGkind('Mersenne-Twister')
set.seed(42)
library(sp)
library(raster)

x <- seq_len(1000)       #Zonal coordinates
y <- seq_len(1000)       #Meridionial coordinates
z <- runif(1000, -5, 5)  #Simulated residuals

my.coords <- data.frame(x, y)
coordinates(my.coords) <- c('x', 'y')
crs(my.coords) <- CRS('+proj=merc +datum=WGS84 +units=m +ellps=WGS84')

library(ncf)
cor.obj <- correlog(x = x, y = y, z = z, latlon = FALSE, increment = 20, resamp = 10)
```

Where `x` are the zonal coordinates, `y` are the meridionial coordinates, `z` are the model residuals I'm running the Moran's I test on, `increment` is the "*increment for the uniformly distributed distance classes*" (from `?ncf::correlog`) and `latlon` being a logical value (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) depending on what coordinate systems `x` and `y` are.

The output object produces a few things, but I'm interested in `correlation` and `x.intercept` outputs:

> **Value**
>
> An object of class "correlog" is returned, consisting of the following components:
>
> `correlation` the value for the moran (or Mantel) similarity.
>
> ...
>
> `x.intercept` the interpolate x.intercept of Epperson (1993).

Calling `?ncf::correlog` doesn't return much in regards to what units are being returned, but I'm convinced that it returns meters if I'm using World Mercator and set the `latlon` argument to `FALSE`. But when I plot the object and call the for the `mean.of.class`, it doesn't make sense:

```
plot(cor.obj)
car.obj$mean.of.class
         1          2          3          4          5          6          7          8          9         10         11 
  10.58345   30.38211   50.18075   69.97939   89.77802  109.57664  129.37525  149.87711  170.38660  190.18517  209.98373 
        12         13         14         15         16         17         18         19         20         21         22 
 229.78226  249.58079  269.37929  289.88057  310.39043  330.18889  349.98732  369.78573  389.58412  409.38248  429.88299 
        23         24         25         26         27         28         29         30         31         32         33 
 450.39330  470.19158  489.98983  509.78805  529.58624  549.38439  569.88385  590.39471  610.19273  629.99070  649.78861 
        34         35         36         37         38         39         40         41         42         43         44 
 669.58647  689.38427  709.88220  730.39377  750.19135  769.98883  789.78622  809.58351  829.38068  849.87619  870.38868 
        45         46         47         48         49         50         51         52         53         54         55 
 890.18541  909.98196  929.77832  949.57445  969.37033  989.86150 1010.37510 1030.16994 1049.96432 1069.75818 1089.55141 
        56         57         58         59         60         61         62         63         64         65         66 
1109.34390 1129.82530 1150.33951 1170.12850 1189.91572 1209.70066 1229.48259 1249.26042 1269.70497 1290.20724 1309.95620 
        67         68         69         70         71 
1329.68162 1349.36177 1368.93628 1388.15163 1404.31407
```

[image]

I've only had 1000 meters in the original `x` and `y` vectors, so why is it plotting it all the way to 1400?

Changing `latlon` to `TRUE` produces this:

```
cor.obj <- correlog(x = my.coords$x, y = my.coords$y, z = z, latlon = TRUE, increment = 20, resamp = 10)
plot(cor.obj)
```

[image]

Converting `my.coords` to latitude/longitude produces this monstrosity:

```
my.coords <- spTransform(my.coords, CRS('+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84'))

cor.obj <- correlog(x = x, y = y, z = z, latlon = TRUE, increment = 20, resamp = 10)
plot(cor.obj)
```

[image]

Changing the `increment` to `0.02` produces something a bit more recognizable but the *distance (mean-of-class)* has changed to what I *think* are kilometers:

```
cor.obj <- correlog(x = my.coords$x, y = my.coords$y, z = z, latlon = T, increment = 0.02, resamp = 10)
plot(cor.obj)
```

[image]

But again, I'm a bit thrown by the x-axis (e.g. call `cor.obj$mean.of.class`), because I only started off with 1000 values in `my.coords`, so why does it go up to 1400? Am I missing something? What unit is being returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The units are meters because the coordinates are meters. The x-axis goes to 1400 because the most distant possible points are `(1,1000),(1000,1)` and the distance between them is `sqrt(2)*1000`.

Comment: So that would mean if coordinates are latitude and longitude, latlon = T, and the increments are appropriate, then the distance is in km?

Comment: I would not expect units in km with or without the latlon argument. The documentation is not completely clear on what that parameter does, but your units are in meters so I would leave it as false.

Comment: For what it's worth I was struggling too to understand the distance unit when latlon=TRUE for the spline.correlog() function. Using lat long values I determined max distance in decimal degrees as max(dist(cbind(data$long,data$lat))), which for me was ~7.6. Using approximate conversion of 1 degree = 111km this equals ~843 km. The max value in my spline.correlog was 812. So I too am thinking km. Documentation on this could be improved.

Comment: I can confirm the latlon distance is in km. In the source code, latlon distance is calculated using the function `gcdist`. `gcdist` returns the distance in km